# texlive on multiple computers

Tags: texlive

I have texlive installed on several computers with linux. I use tlmgr to update texlive on each computer. Could it be possible to do this on one only and update on the others for example by using "rsync" on the texlive directories ?

Comment: Welcome! How did you install TeX Live? If you used upstream's installer rather than your distros' packages the this should work if the architectures are the same. If not, you'd need to add the relevant architectures. I've done this, I think. However, I did it when there was no TL on the target computer and afterwards used `tlmgr` normally. You might need to ensure they are at the same point to begin if using `rsync`, though I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. As cfr pointed out in his comment, it is easiest when both are using the same architecture. If you use different archs you only need to install all of them with `tlmgr arch add ....`.

After that it is a simple case of setting the `PATH` correct for the respective computer.

Concerning `rsync`: I would do a `rsync -avz --delete` to make sure that files are also removed on the receiving end.

There is only one point that needs attention: Available fonts and the font maps generated in `TEXMFSYSVAR`. If you have different `TEXMFLOCAL` with different `updmap.cfg` files, the generated font maps will not be the same, and syncing `TEXMFSYSVAR` would not be the optimal solution. In this case do *not* sync `TEXMFSYSVAR`, but after the sync run `fmtutil-sys --all` and `updmap-sys`. That should be enough.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. All the architectures are the same. It works.